# How to trigger unison sync files and directories when there's any change on OSX?

Tags: synchronization, unison

I have a need to sync two directories on OSX. I find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936627/two-way-sync-with-rsync) recommending using unison.

I tried unison, it seems it can sync two directories very well. But it doesn't do synchronization automatically( always keep two directories synced when there's any change ).

So I guess to accomplish my purpose, unison should be used with a trigger which will watch changes and notify unison to do its work.

But how to do that? Any recommendation and tutorial?

Answer (score 6):

Unison has this capability built in. Just add the line `repeat = watch` to your Unison profile.

Answer (score 2):

Install Unison:

```
brew install unison
```

Install unox:

```
git clone git@github.com:hnsl/unox.git
cd unox
ln -s $PWD/unox.py /usr/local/bin/unison-fsmonitor
```

Do the initial sync:

```
unison -auto -batch dirA dirB
```

Run the continuous bidirectional sync:

```
unison -auto -batch -repeat watch -times dirA dirB
```

Answer (score 1):

I find the npm module `fsmonitor` for watching content changes in a directory.

first I write a small script to sync the folders I want with unison like:

```
unison -auto -batch dirA dirB
unison -auto -batch dirB dirA
```

install the module in global: `npm install -g fsmonitor`.
run command in shell: `fsmonitor -d <the dir> <sync script>`.
Then any change happens in the directory, the sync script will be executed, and the two directories will be in sync.

Answer (score 1):

Using `repeat = watch` in your unison profile in [the .unison directory](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#unisondir) will do the trick. (I tried on Ubuntu 18.04)

**Step 1**, edit unison profile, $HOME/.unison/example.prf

```
root = /tmp/data1
root = /tmp/data2

path = shared

repeat = watch
```

**Step 2**, start unison

```
$ unison example
```

**Step 3**, create a file in either root, and it will be synced automatically by unison to the other.

```
$ touch /tmp/data1/shared/1.txt
$ ls /tmp/data2/shared/
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 user1    0 Mar 26 16:25 1.txt
```

**Appendix**

1. You can install unison in Ubuntu by running `sudo apt-get install unison`
2. To use `repeat = watch`, you'll need `unison-fsmonitor`

```
$ curl -L -o unison-fsmonitor https://github.com/TentativeConvert/Syndicator/raw/master/unison-binaries/unison-fsmonitor
$ which unison
/usr/bin/unison
$ sudo cp unison-fsmonitor /usr/bin/
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/unison-fsmonitor
```